# Lie algebra and rotation

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to find the rotation about the x axis in three dimensions by the lie algebra:
$$R(\theta) = I + A$$
where $$A = \theta_{x}J_{x}+\theta_{y}J_{y}+\theta_{z}J_{z}$$
Since we want rotation about x axis
$$A = \theta_{x}J_{x}$$
Not just:
$$R(\theta) = R(\frac{\theta}{N})^{N} = e^{J\theta} = cos(\theta_{x}) + J_{x}sin(\theta_{x})$$
So that
$$\begin{pmatrix}
cos\theta_{x} & 0 &0 \\ 
0 &cos\theta_{x}  & sin\theta_{x}\\ 
0 & -sin\theta_{x} &cos\theta_{x} 
\end{pmatrix}$$

But this is wrong... Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$e^{\theta J}=\cos\theta I+\sin\theta J$ is not true. You seem to be assuming $J$ is a square root of $-I$, but actually it squares to the diagonal matrix ${\rm diag}(0,-1,-1)$, which is why your upper left corner is wrong.

Comment: Hi. Thank you, but i think i do not understand yet. Is not $$R(\theta) = e^{\sum_{i} \theta_{i} J_{i}}$$ true?

Now begin theta y and z zero, shouldn't it reduces to what i put?

Comment: Did you read my answer? I pointed out $e^{\theta J}$ doesn't equal $\cos\theta I+\sin\theta J$ like you say it does. I'm guessing you thought this based on the mistaken assumption that $J^2=-I$, but $J_x^2$ actually has a $0$ in the top left.